# What is the time complexity in chained hash table

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, hashtable

I've a hashtable which consists of 1000 elements and 100 buckets with maximum 100 entries per bucket. Suppose one bucket has 100 entries (i.e. 100 items in the list of that bucket). Now what will be the time complexity in terms of big-O notation if the item I sought is the 100th in the list of the bucket. O(100) or O(n)? Or anything else?

Comment: I don´t get your data structure

Comment: It's hashtable with 100 buckets and chaining of maximum 100 items per bucket in case of collision..

Comment: So the maximal count of elements is somewhere between 100 and 10000, depending on the values? Well... if we measure how many elements have to be searched: O(1) because searching 100 (independent from the total count in the hashtable) is constant. Btw. O(1)==O(100)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of big-O notation is that you do not "suppose one bucket has 100 entries", you let the number of its entries be `n`, and get an expression in terms of `n`.

For `n` entries in the list, the time complexity will be `O(n)`, ignoring whatever hash function you're using.

Note that this is worst case (the last item), and on average the search runs in `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't meaningful, because big-O notation expresses how the efficiency changes as the number of elements changes, e.g. the number of elements increases past 1000, and you haven't told us the behaviour.

For example, the big-O notation efficiency for ***finding that specific element*** might be:

- if the bucket that element's at the end of will never have more than 100 elements, then O(1)
- if the element stays at position 100 in that bucket, then even if further items are appended after it, then assuming searching will be from the start of the bucket then it's still O(1)
- if the number of elements in that bucket stay at N/10, and you can't count on that specific element remaining at a fixed position in the bucket's list, then it's O(N)
- if the element stays at the end of that bucket but the number of elements therein is always the cubed root of N squared, then O(squared(cubed root(N)))
- if the element stays at the end of that bucket and the number of elements therein is always around 3 * sqrt(N), then O(sqrt(N))

As you can see, O is relating search time to total number of elements, but you haven't given enough data points to describe a curve.